# Multiple TOC's in Android

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am trying to achieve this style of TOC of an iPad on an Android app.

[image: Multiple toc hierarchical navigation in iPad app]

The toc's can be swiped back in to the screen and multiple levels are visible at once.
I think there is a similar concept with the new Evernote app -but I am not sure how to start with this. How can I achieve this? Is it as simple as just multiple viewpagers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you are looking for, it does exactly what you need:

https://github.com/Mapsaurus/Android-PanesLibrary